# Spring WS 2.0.2 : Using StAX with @Endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, spring-ws

I'm trying to use StAX with Spring WS 2.0.2 but I'm not having any luck getting it working. I found an example online [here](http://www.redstream.nl/2008/06/14/using-stax-with-spring-ws/) but it uses AbstractStaxStreamPayloadEndpoint which is now deprecated in Spring WS 2.x. I'm trying to use the @Endpoint annotation approach but I am getting the following error:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring xml:lang="en">No adapter for endpoint [public void com.endpoint.AddressTypeEndpoint.handleReadAddressTypeRequest(javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader,javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter) throws java.lang.Exception]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?</faultstring>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And here is the code for my endpoint:

```
package com.endpoint;

import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamWriter;

import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;

@Endpoint
public class AddressTypeEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://client/AddressType";

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "ReadAddressTypeRequest")
    public void handleReadAddressTypeRequest(XMLStreamReader streamreader, XMLStreamWriter streamwriter) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Got to the endpoint");
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can use StAX with Spring WS, using @Endpoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try annotating the method parameter:

```
 @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "ReadAddressTypeRequest")
 public void handleReadAddressTypeRequest(
      @RequestPayload XMLStreamReader streamreader) throws Exception {... }
```

[Edit] For the response, annotate the method with `@ResponsePayload`, and return one of the objects listed here http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#d4e1220 (instead of `void`)

Comment: Your suggestion worked but now there's nothing in the response. How do I send the response (using Stax or any other method)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using @ResponsePayload as explained in the Spring WS doc at: http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/reference/html/server.html